# Using two different ld_library_paths at runtime

Tags: c++, library-path

I want to execute a c++ program that starts 2 sub-programs.
The problem is, that one program needs another library path as the other program. 
So I have something like this:
-_Parent program execution
--->setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH-> Execute first child program
--->setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH new -> Execute second child program

How can I achieve that (or isn't this possible at runtime?). 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can append more than one path with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` flag. Or am I missing what you're asking?

Comment: The problem is, that i need in the path one library, but with two different compile options. If I append them both in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, my programs will chose always the first. But I want program A to chose the libraryXa and program B libraryXb. LibraryX can only be compiled to support C++ OR CUDA, but not both -.- , and one program needs the library with C++ support, the other the same library with CUDA support.  That's why I have to do this like this. Hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: Yes, that does, however, I have no idea how to fix that. Sorry!